# Cannot exit full screen in Pantheon terminal

Tags: elementary-os

Pantheon terminal is always in full screen. I cannot find ant way to change change the size of the terminal. Can someone please help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to exit full screen mode, or to make windowed mode your default...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exit fullscreen by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Some laptops require the `Function` key to be pressed at the same time. For my laptop I have to use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: okay. That was simple. Felling a little embarrassed now

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in Elementary OS

Yeah that's true sometimes terminal just toggles itself into  full screen mode and toggle bar becomes invisible

Use **F11** to bring back it to normal window size even [***windows key+down arrow***] wont work in this situation